# OpenCL: different work kernel code for the x86 and x64 versions

Tags: c++

```
//////////////////////////////////
// host code
//////////////////////////////////

// ...
// select device / create context / build program
// ...

cl_kernel k_func_Test = nullptr;

k_func_Test = clCreateKernel(prog, "k_Test", &error);

size_t localsize = 3;
size_t globalsize = localsize * 2;

error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, k_func_Test, 1, NULL, &globalsize_, &localsize_, 0, nullptr, nullptr);

clFinish(command_queue);

//////////////////////////////////
// kernel code
//////////////////////////////////

__kernel void k_Test()
{
    if ( (get_group_id(0) + get_group_id(1) + get_group_id(2)) == 0 &&
         (get_local_id(0) + get_local_id(1) + get_local_id(2)) == 0)
    {
        printf( "get_global_size = %d x %d x %d | " \
                "get_local_size = %d x %d x %d | " \
                "get_work_dim = %d \n" \
                "////////////////////////////////////\n", \
                get_global_size(0), get_global_size(1), get_global_size(2), \
                get_local_size(0), get_local_size(1), get_local_size(2), \
                get_work_dim()
                );
    }

    printf( "get_group_id = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "get_global_id = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "get_local_id = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "get_num_groups = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "////////////////////////////////////\n", \
            get_group_id(0), get_group_id(1), get_group_id(2), \
            get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1), get_global_id(2), \
            get_local_id(0), get_local_id(1), get_local_id(2), \
            get_num_groups(0), get_num_groups(1), get_num_groups(2)
            );
}
```

I have 3 devices:

1) Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz

2) Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600

3) GeForce GTX 780 Ti

For all devices for x86 I get about these results:

```
////////////////////////////////////
get_global_size = 6 x 1 x 1 | get_local_size = 3 x 1 x 1 | get_work_dim = 1
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 3 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 2 x 1 x 1
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 4 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 2 x 1 x 1
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 5 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 2 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 2 x 1 x 1
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 2 x 1 x 1
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 2 x 1 x 1
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 2 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 2 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 2 x 1 x 1
////////////////////////////////////
```

But, I start for x64 I got very different results. For "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600" - results were as in x86 version.

But for "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz" and "GeForce GTX 780 Ti" I got follows results:

```
////////////////////////////////////
get_global_size = 6 x 0 x 1 | get_local_size = 0 x 1 x 0 | get_work_dim = 3
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 3 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 0 x 0 x 0
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 4 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 0 x 0 x 0
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 5 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 0 x 0 x 0
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 0 x 0 x 0
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 1 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 0 x 0 x 0
////////////////////////////////////
get_group_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_global_id = 0 x 0 x 0
get_local_id = 2 x 0 x 0
get_num_groups = 0 x 0 x 0
////////////////////////////////////
```

So, As we can see the results of the very different. For example in function "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" we set the parameter work_dim = 1, but I do not understand why for x64 version app - it works differently! and get_work_dim() get 1 or 3 (for last I think get value of local_work_size).

Maybe someone experienced this? implementation of different drivers? What is it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem here could be in the format specifiers you are using when calling printf.

The OpenCL C built-ins get_global_size(), get_local_size(), get_num_groups(), get_global_id(), get_local_id() and get_group_id() all return a size_t value. The size_t type is different depending on the architecture's address width; it's size is equal to the size of a pointer (i.e. sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(void *)), therefore on x86 size_t is 4bytes and on x86_64 size_t is 8bytes. Because of this printf has the "%zu" format specifier for size_t values. This might explain why you were seeing different outputs on x86 and x86_64 kernel builds.

Additionally the OpenCL C built-in get_work_dim() returns an unsigned int value, and for this you should use the "%u" format specifier.

Maybe try this for your kernel instead:

```
__kernel void k_Test()
{
    if ( (get_group_id(0) + get_group_id(1) + get_group_id(2)) == 0 &&
         (get_local_id(0) + get_local_id(1) + get_local_id(2)) == 0)
    {
        printf( "get_global_size = %zu x %zu x %zu | " \
                "get_local_size = %zu x %zu x %zu | " \
                "get_work_dim = %u \n" \
                "////////////////////////////////////\n", \
                get_global_size(0), get_global_size(1), get_global_size(2), \
                get_local_size(0), get_local_size(1), get_local_size(2), \
                get_work_dim()
                );
    }

    printf( "get_group_id = %zu x %zu x %zu \n" \
            "get_global_id = %zu x %zu x %zu \n" \
            "get_local_id = %zu x %zu x %zu \n" \
            "get_num_groups = %zu x %zu x %zu \n" \
            "////////////////////////////////////\n", \
            get_group_id(0), get_group_id(1), get_group_id(2), \
            get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1), get_global_id(2), \
            get_local_id(0), get_local_id(1), get_local_id(2), \
            get_num_groups(0), get_num_groups(1), get_num_groups(2)
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **AerialMantis** rights! The problem of the function *printf* on kernel. After my changes in function Test() in the work function was the same and forecasting on all platforms.

```
__kernel void k_Test()
{
    if ( (get_group_id(0) + get_group_id(1) + get_group_id(2)) == 0 &&
         (get_local_id(0) + get_local_id(1) + get_local_id(2)) == 0)
    {
        printf( "get_global_size = %d x %d x %d | " \
                "get_local_size = %d x %d x %d | " \
                "get_work_dim = %d \n" \
                "////////////////////////////////////\n", \
                (int)get_global_size(0), (int)get_global_size(1), (int)get_global_size(2), \
                (int)get_local_size(0), (int)get_local_size(1), (int)get_local_size(2), \
                (int)get_work_dim()
                );
    }

    printf( "get_group_id = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "get_global_id = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "get_local_id = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "get_num_groups = %d x %d x %d \n" \
            "////////////////////////////////////\n", \
            (int)get_group_id(0), (int)get_group_id(1), (int)get_group_id(2), \
            (int)get_global_id(0), (int)get_global_id(1), (int)get_global_id(2), \
            (int)get_local_id(0), (int)get_local_id(1), (int)get_local_id(2), \
            (int)get_num_groups(0), (int)get_num_groups(1), (int)get_num_groups(2)
            );
}
```

Following the recommendations and use %u and %zu format specifiers I wrote follow code:

```
__kernel void k_Test2()
{
    printf( "get_work_dim = %u get_global_id = %zu x %zu x %zu \n", get_work_dim(), get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1), get_global_id(2));
}
```

And understood: specifier %u - works! %zu - does not work on all platforms. For example Intel HD return "Invalid Expression: (null) ERROR: printf has thrown an exception". So I made a casting in function k_Test by adding the prefix (int).